# How to silence certain deprecation warnings from a Rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Is there way to suppress deprecation warnings on a line-by-line basis? I'm working on an old app that has a plugin causing deprecation warnings. I'd rather not change that plugin's code manually. But I could alter it to not show the warnings.

My tests look like garbage with all those warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but this seems to do the trick:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence do
  # no warnings for any use of deprecated methods here
end
```